# foreign key db_schema.xml automatic renamed to FK_ magento 2

Tags: magento2, foreign-key, db-schema

I have this db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <!-- Setup table vendor_shipping_option -->
    <table name="vendor_shipping_option" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column name="rate_id" xsi:type="int" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID" />
        <column name="name" xsi:type="varchar" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Name" />
        <column name="description" xsi:type="text" nullable="true" comment="Description" />
        <column name="type" xsi:type="varchar" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Type" />
        <column name="source" xsi:type="varchar" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Source" />
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="rate_id" />
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="VENDORSHIPPING_SOURCE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE" table="vendor_shipping_option" column="source" referenceTable="inventory_source" referenceColumn="source_code" onDelete="CASCADE" />
    </table>

    <!-- Setup table vendor_shipping_click_and_collect_availability -->
    <table name="vendor_shipping_click_and_collect_availability" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column name="rate_id" xsi:type="int" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity ID" />
        <column name="click_and_collect_window_id" xsi:type="int" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="true" comment="Click And Collect Window Id"/>
        <column name="day" xsi:type="varchar" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Day" />
        <column name="delivery_hours" xsi:type="varchar" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Delivery Hours" />
        <column name="start" xsi:type="datetime" on_update="false" nullable="true" comment="Start"/>
        <column name="end" xsi:type="datetime" on_update="false" nullable="true" comment="End"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="VENDORSHIPPING_CAC_AVAI_RATE_ID_VENDORSHIPPING_RATE_ID" table="vendor_shipping_click_and_collect_availability" column="rate_id" referenceTable="vendor_shipping_option" referenceColumn="rate_id" onDelete="CASCADE" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then i run setup command, and in db i got foreign key `VENDORSHIPPING_CAC_AVAI_RATE_ID_VENDORSHIPPING_RATE_ID` changed to `FK_A9DDDF3AAD5A318C723BEEE21737E6A0`.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your file is up-to-date there are no issues when running the command. if an error then deletes both tables from DB and Again run the upgrade command or you can also change your referenceId.

Comment: @Msquare i've follow your instruction, but not working, do you have other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your Table and remove your module entry from the "setup_module" table

now run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

then run `php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module`

Comment: sorry for late reply, but it doesn't work, do you have other solutions?

Comment: I think you are using wrong logic of creating `foreign key constrains` so this is causing, please compare logic syntax from magento2 schema.

Comment: @ZahidH can you tell more detail about this? with the same syntax, i've successfully in created 3 other tables that have foreign key.